# Relation between t-value and correlation coefficient r

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, t-test, effect-size, linear-algebra

Page 6 of [**this article**](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED433353.pdf) shows that following holds for an "*independent samples t-test*".

I was wondering how the equation to the Right of equal sign would change if we consider a "*paired samples t-test*"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paired t-test is just a univariate t-test, so a correlation coefficient isn't even available.

You may be confused about the RHS because the correlation doesn't represent the correlation from one sample as an X value against the other sample as a Y value. Rather, a t-test is equivalent to a linear regression model where the group indication is assigned a 0 for one group and a 1 for another. Only in this fashion can we consider the correlation coefficient when there may be 50 people in group a but 66 people in group b.

This image from [here](http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/treg.htm) summarizes the idea using violin plots and a scatter with trendline.[image]

Comment: A paired t-test concerns a hypothesis about the difference of marginal means of a bivariate distribution.  The data $(x_i,y_i)$ are a sample of that distribution.  Why, then, is a correlation coefficient not "available"?  Did you perhaps mean to write that the (obvious) correlation coefficient is not *relevant?*

Comment: @whuber Indeed it does, but the same hypothesis could be tested different ways. The paired t-test is a conditional likelihood approach to testing that hypothesis. I clarified that the correlation which the OP speaks of is rather between the unconditional responses and their respective *group* indicator. Using this approach with paired data is counter to intuition.